# java 8 change list to map using instance of list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm try to convert a list to a map using the `Collectors.toMap` call.  The list consists of `ActivityReconcile` objects.  I want to pass an instance for every entry in the list into the `toMap` call.

The code is below and where I need the instances is denoted by ??.

```
final List<ActivityReconcile> activePostedList = loader.loadActivePosted(accessToken);
Map<AccountTransactionKey, ActivityReconcile> postedActiveMap = 
activePostedList.stream().collect(
 Collectors.toMap(
 AccountTransactionKey.createNewAccountTransactionKeyFromActivityReconcileRecord(??),??));
```

Comment: The question is unclear to *me*. Would you mind specifiying please?

Comment: Map takes two arguments: key and value. So, what is the key and value of the expected output Map?

Comment: `toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)` This method takes two arguments. How do you propose the key and/or values to be determined?

Man, look at that method name! `createNewAccountTransactionKeyFromActivityReconcileRecord`

Comment: the key is AccountTransactionKey.createNewAccountTransactionKeyFromActivityReconcileRecord(??) where ?? is an instance of a ActivityReconcile object from the list,  and value is also an instance of an instance of a ActivityReconcile object from the list.  I need the instance, not call into specific methods with the object.

Comment: Sorry method name is legacy code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you will need something like

```
Map<AccountTransactionKey, ActivityReconcile> result = choices
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                      AccountTransactionKey::generate,
                      Function.identity()));
```

And the method (in `AccountTransactionKey` class) will look like

```
public static AccountTransactionKey generate(ActivityReconcile reconcile) {...}
```

---

I've replaced `createNewAccountTransactionKeyFromActivityReconcileRec` by `generate` for making the answer more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 3):

To "fix" your code with the least changes, add a lambda parameter:

```
activePostedList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
  ar -> AccountTransactionKey.createNewAccountTransactionKeyFromActivityReconcileRecord(ar)),
  o -> o));
```

or use a method reference:

```
activePostedList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
  AccountTransactionKey::createNewAccountTransactionKeyFromActivityReconcileRecord, o -> o));
```

btw, I can't recall ever seeing a method name as long as `createNewAccountTransactionKeyFromActivityReconcileRecord` - for readability, consider reducing it to just `create()`, since the return type and parameter type are enough to distinguish it from other factory methods you may have.